# Amazon api not returning results aligned with the amazon website results

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I'm using the [python-amazon-product-api](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/0.2.5a1) to create a search bar which will return results similar to the results returned on the amazon site. However, when I do an itemSearch, as follows, I get some results, but it only returns products which are sold and shipped by amazon. I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this.

```
 root = api.item_search('All', Keywords=searchWord, ResponseGroup='Large', ItemPage=pageNo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the 'MerchantId' parameter to 'All':

```
root = api.item_search('All', Keywords=searchWord, ResponseGroup='Large', ItemPage=pageNo, MerchantId='All')
```

If you don't specify it, it will be defaulted to "Amazon", which is why you see only Amazon's products (please refer to the [Item Search](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?ItemSearch.html) documentation for more information)

---

To answer your comment, here is the code I have tried out:

```
AWS_KEY = '...'
SECRET_KEY = '...'
searchWord = "Lenovo"
pageNo = "1"

api = API(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, 'us')

result = api.item_search('All', Keywords=searchWord, ResponseGroup='Large', ItemPage=pageNo, MerchantId='All')
for item in result.Items.Item:
    print item.ItemAttributes.Title
```

This yields the following results (as of 05/28/2011)

- Lenovo G560 Series 067999U Laptop (Black)
- Lenovo G560 Series 0679ALU 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)
- Lenovo Multimedia Remote with Keyboard
- Lenovo G560 Series 0679AKU 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)
- Lenovo Ideapad Z560 09143YU 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)
- Lenovo IdeaPad U260 08763DU 12.5-Inch Ultraportable Laptop (Clementine Orange)
- Lenovo Ideacentre H405 77231AU Desktop (Black)
- Lenovo ThinkPad 0578F7U Notebook - Core i3 i3-370M 2.4GHz - 14-Inch - [...]
- Lenovo G560 Series 0679AJU 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)
- Lenovo Ideapad G550 2958-9PU 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)

This seems to be the exact 10 items that are currently showing up on the Amazon Search page you linked to in your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I added that, the results have improved a lot. However, it's still missing a bunch of them. For example, when I search for 'Lenovo' the first two results from http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lenovo&x=0&y=0 still don't show up. Can you think of anything else I could do to improve the results? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I had carelessly placed some try: except: blocks, which had the program skip over some results. Thanks for your reply :)